# HTML Fixed Width? (No scroll bar)

Tags: html, web, width

I want to have a set width for my page with no horizontal scroll bar. (And if my elements exceed the page width, they don't add width or a horizontal scroll bar to the page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the best user experience, but this is what you need to add to your CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```